# Android identical gen identifiers for different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I have a project with some layouts and I'm linking to it from another project which also has its own layouts. The problem is that it causes duplicate identifiers, so when I'm trying to inflate a layout from one of the projects, I'm getting the layout with the same identifier from the other project. How can I settle this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using full paths like `com.my.first.package.name.R.layout.sameId` and `com.my.second.package.name.R.layout.sameId`

Comment: To add note to this, by default you will use the highest level resource file by default, so you should only need to explicitly define library package names

Comment: Tried it, same error. I actually don't think it matters if I add the package name or not, because it still translates to the same identifier.

Comment: Then try creating file `values/ids.xml` like described here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

Comment: I don't understand how this can solve the issue. The layouts get their ids automatically. This file is only for widgets ids.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem using someother identifiers in your layout as far you do not have two resources with the same id in the same inflatable resource or share the same root view.

That's like using @android:id/text1 ids in your layouts.

If that's a problem, why not just rename your own ids?

Comment: I meant layout identifiers, not widget identifiers.